# what is the reason for the error TypeError: init() missing 2 required positional arguments:

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python I have an error with this code in python  3 where when I run it I get a message saying:

> TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'pid'
>   and 'memory'

btw: this is a programme to replicate a ram
can someone tell me the reason for this error

my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, p, s, e, bh):
        self.p = None
        self.s = 400 
        self.e = None
        self.bh = True
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self,pid,memory):
        self.pid = pid
        self.memory = memory
        self.head = None
        self.numnodes = 0

    def insertFirst(self, p, s, e, bh):
        node = Node(p, s, e, bh)
        node.next = self.head
        self.head = node
        self.numnodes += 1

    def insertLast(self, p, m):
        node = Node(p, m)
        if self.numnodes == 0:
            self.head = node
            self.numnodes += 1
            return
        cur_node = self.head
        while cur_node.next != None:
            cur_node = cur_node.next
        cur_node.next = node
        self.numnodes += 1

    def remFirst(self):
        self.head = self.head.next
        self.numnodes -= 1

    def remLast(self):
        cur_node = self.head
        while cur_node.next != None:
            p_node = cur_node
            cur_node = cur_node.get_next()
        del cur_node
        p_node.next = None
        self.numnodes -= 1

    def getFirst(self):
        return self.head

    def getLast(self):
        cur_node = self.head
        while cur_node.next != None:
            cur_node = cur_node.next
        return cur_node

class Memory:
      def __init__(self,pid,memory):
            self.list = LinkedList()
            self.list.insertFirst(pid,memory)
            self.memory = memory
            self.pid = pid

      def allocate(self,pid,memory):
            temp_node=self.list.head
            while temp_node.bh != True:
                  temp_node.next = temp_node
                  if temp_node.next.bh == True:
                        temp_node.next.s=temp_node.e
                        temp_node.next.e=temp_node.next.s +memory
                        temp_node.bh = False
                  if temp_node.next == None:
                        break
                  while temp_node.e + memory +1 < 2560 :

                        self.list.insertLast(self, p, s, e, bh)
                        self.p += 1
                        self.s = temp_node.e
                        self.e = temp_node.e + memory
                        self.bh = True

            else: print("no space")


      def terminate(self,pid):
            temp_node=self.list.head
            while temp_node.pid != pid: 
                  temp_node.next = temp_node
                  if temp_node.next == None:
                        print("no such processs")
```

m = Memory()

m.allocate(1,400)

Comment: It probably comes from `self.list = LinkedList()` see the arguments in the _init method of this class